# Change line Color in the lineChart Example on the Gadget Server

Tags: wso2, google-gadget

I am running the lineChart gadget example which makes use of the visualization framework on the gadget server. It runs fine with data being displayed every second. I want to change the color of the line but I cannot find any method inside the gadget code which can set the line color.  In the following piece of code you can set some properties.

```
           window.onload = function () {

            var lineChart = new wso2vis.s.chart.protovis.LineChart("chart","MNT-Lab : LabVIEW Simulation","");

            lineChart.dataField(["Response", "Terminal"])
                .dataValue(["Value"])
                .dataLabel(["Name"])
                .width(380)
                .height(300)
                .band(50)
                .legend(true)
                .marks(true)
                .dirFromLeft(true)
                .xSuffix("s");
```

But i am a bit confused on how and where the default color of the line is being set. I have looked inside the wso2vis.js file but cannot see any methods to change the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2Vis.js is renamed to viskit.js and is now hosted at GitHub [1]. for your question you can change the rgba values in [2].

Regards,
Nuwan

[1] http://wso2.github.com/viskit/
[2] https://github.com/wso2/viskit/blob/master/js/subscriber/chart/protovis/LineChart.js

Comment: Thanks for reply, Are there any examples of Gadgets for the gadget server which use the viskit,js

Comment: Nuwan thanks for reply, Are there any examples of Gadgets for the gadget server which use the viskit.js. Would it not be better and easier to be able to change color in the gadget code just like some of the other properties shown above instead of having to edit the javascript file.